# Pooled dataset. Possible?

Tags: spss, dataset, data-imputation, pooling

I work with SPSS 22.

I had a dataset and run Multiple (100) Imputation on it. Received the output and someone significant variables.

The cases in my dataset have a specific outcome, and I would like to see what kind of outcome I would get after running ordinal regression on the new dataset. The ordinal regression gives me an outcome for every Imputations. But I would like to get the outcome for the pooled one.

I tried to make a pooled dataset, by following the steps on https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_one_create_a_pooled_dataset_in_SPSS_for_further_analysis

1. When you run multiple imputation in SPSS the default setup runs 5 iterations and writes the data to either a new SPSS file or saves it as a new SPSS file [You have to specify the choice]. In the new file the first column gets labelled as "Imputation_"  is the iteration number starting with Original Data, then 1 [indicating iteration no 1] and so on. Let us call this file splitdata.sav
2. You can use the "splitdata.sav" file for further analysis directly and SPSS should take care of pooling. Click Data -> Split File. In the dialog box select "Imputation_" and move it to "Groups Based On:" box. Check "Compare Groups". Now any analysis that you run should get run on Original Data, Iteration No 1 data, Iteration No 2 data... and the pooled data. This is a real advantage of SPSS cos you can check the results of the original data along with the various imputations and the pooled data simultaneously.
3. If you want to physically seperate the files use Data -> Select Cases -> Set your condition [Usually the If condition] -> and output to -> A new dataset -> dataset name. In this way you can create separate data files which will contain original data and data from imputations.
4. If you have separated the datasets in to different files [as in step 3] and want to pool them into a single file use Data -> Merge File -> Add Variables. But be sure to change the names of the variables in the datafiles created in step 3. Slight differences in the variable names will do [say v01, v02, ... v05] cos SPSS will not be able to merge the variables if they have the same name. Once all the variables are in the same file you can create new pooled variables [v0P = v01 +v02 + v03 +v04 + v05]

[you may also look at the use of Data -> Aggregate function]

But now I am stuck. Is it possible to have a pooled dataset?